# How to pass the match when using render in Route component from react router (v4)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When declaring a route like this:

App.js

`<Route path="/:id" component={RunningProject} />`

I can obtain the id param in RunningProject.js like this

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    console.log(props.match.params.id);
}
```

But when declaring the route like this

`<Route path="/:id" render={() => <RunningProject getProjectById={this.getProject} />} />`

I get an error because match no longer get passed into the props.

How can I pass the match object into the `props` using `render=` instead of `component=` ?

Answer (score 28):

In order to pass the match object you need to deconstruct the object passed as parameter to the render callback like this:

`<Route path="/:id" render={({match}) => <RunningProject getProjectById={this.getProject} match={match} />} />`

You can also get the other objects, here's a list of the objects passed:

- `history`
- `location`
- `staticContext`
- `match`

Or you could just pass the whole object, and deconstruct in the recipient component

`<Route path="/:id" render={(obj) => <RunningProject getProjectById={this.getProject} obj={obj} />} />`

Answer (score 2):

*In complement of @juliangonzalez (good) answer:*

Better to make your component not "route" aware, so instead of passing React match object you should do:

```
<Route path="/:id" render={({match}) => 
    <RunningProject getProjectById={this.getProject} projectId={match.params.id} />
} />
```